# Android virtual keyboard hides the bottom most EdiText (multiline)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a issue with a Android keyboard, but I can not find it anywhere after a while searching around the internet.

Android virtual keyboard hides the bottom most EdiText (multiline) :

[image]

i tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize but with no result

my XML code :

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_prod_info1_after2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textstyle2"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

use  **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"** in you Manifest file. See [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for your reference